# Data loading time is same though Cache used

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I used following method. But it every time it loads it takes huge time.What could be possible reason for that?

```
public function crudsList()
{
     $cruds = Cache::remember('cruds',10, function(){
        return Crud::all();
     });
     return view('cruds_view',compact('cruds'));
}

    @foreach($cruds as $row)
        <tr>
           <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
           <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
           <td>{{$row->color}}</td>
           <td>{{$row->created_at}}</td>
           <td>{{$row->updated_at}}25</td>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: How did you measured? Can you please share the benchmark